# SWift SKShapeNode Mulitple Line thickness and Colors

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Can I have a path with multiple line thickness and colors in one SkShapenode?
For Example

Can I add three different color circles with different fills and stroke size borders all within one node?

Answer (score 0):

skshapenodes arent really supposed to be used in your final product.  theyre used more for testing game concepts out.  if youre finding yourself needing to style them it might be time to make some images.  either make one static image.. or if you need them to be dynamic i might create a white circle image. create three sprites out of this image.  add them on top of one another and change their colors dynamically.

Comment: Thats not really true, there is nothing wrong with using SKShapeNodes in your final product if used sparingly.

Comment: if used sparingly.. meaning theyre not great for performance.  theyve also had a lot of bugs in the past